# TypeError on changing the __class__ attribute of socket object

Tags: python, sockets

There is the following server code (I am defining a class that inherits from socket and am trying to use that class to call the send method on the client socket):

```
import socket

class LogSocket(socket.socket):
    def send(self, data):
        print("Sending {0} to {1}".format(
            data, self.getpeername()[0]))
        super().send(data)

def respond(client):
    response = input("Enter a value: ")
    client.send(bytes(response, 'utf8'))
    client.close()

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(('',2401))
server.listen(1)
try:
    while True:
        client, addr = server.accept()
        client.__class__ = LogSocket
        respond(client)
finally:
    server.close()
```

The client code is:

```
import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(('localhost', 2401))
print("Received: {0}".format(client.recv(1024)))
client.close()
```

When I run the above code, the server crashes with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "10_04_server.py", line 20, in <module>
    client.__class__ = LogSocket
TypeError: __class__ assignment: 'LogSocket' object layout differs from 'socket'
```

What does this error mean? Why is it occurring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `__slots__` attribute to `()`, and this will work:

```
class LogSocket(socket.socket):
    __slots__ = ()
    def send(self, data):
        print("Sending {0} to {1}".format(
            data, self.getpeername()[0]))
        super().send(data)
```

The [relevant pieces of documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots) are:

> The action of a `__slots__` declaration is limited to the class where it is defined. As a result, subclasses will have a `__dict__` unless they also define `__slots__` (which must only contain names of any additional slots).

And

> `__class__` assignment works only if both classes have the same `__slots__`.

Comment: Thanks it worked. The error message is not very helpful.

Comment: The socket class has a non-empty `__slots__` value while we are assigning an empty value. If the classes have unequal `__slots__`, then how is the `__class__` assignment working?

Comment: Read the first documentation snippet again. `__slots__` in a subclass is the _additional_ slots.